# Creating a date range using today's date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, range

I am trying to create a report than users can run in the future. I need to specify a date range which in this case would be the last 6 weeks of data. The date field I am using in this report is app_receipt_date. I am just trying to learn how to use a function similar to excels today() function.

Here is the sql statement. Ignore the dates that was the last instance I ran this. Again, I am trying to 'automate' this moving forward.

```
  select a.underwriting_app_id,
   q.underwriting_quote_id,
   a.application_source,
   q.insured_id,
   q.policy_year,
   a.underwriting_rep,
   --b.marketing_rep,
   a.mail_name,
   a.app_receipt_date,
   a.effective_date,
   a.expiration_date,
   SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(a.effective_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 1,2) as Month,
   a.underwriting_app_status,
   s.description,
   a.last_status_date,
   a.governing_class_code_id,
   q.annual_premium,
   q.create_date,
   q.create_user

 from underwriting_app a,
 app_quote q,
 underwriting_app_status s


where a.underwriting_app_id = q.underwriting_app_id and
  a.underwriting_app_status = s.underwriting_app_status and
  --a.agency_no = b.agency_no (+) and
  q.active_quote_flag = 'Y' and
  a.app_receipt_date > to_date('04-Nov-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') and
  a.app_receipt_date < to_date('17-Dec-2012','dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Brad

Comment: Which database are you using?  And adding some actual SQL code would clarify the question.

Comment: I dont know if this answers your question. I am in PL/SQL developer. 9.0? Is that right? Sorry and thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in Oracle, use 'SYSDATE' for the current date and you can add days with direct addition and subtraction.  If you're OK assuming a week is 7 days, you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM Your_Table
WHERE app_receipt_date > SYSDATE - (6 * 7);
```

Where the "* 7" is just to indicate that you're multiplying six weeks by seven days each.

Comment: +1 "assuming a week is 7 days" - I admire this! I wish more developers would stop to think about the assumptions they are building into their applications :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using T-SQL you can use the GETDATE() function to get today's date, you can then use the DATEADD() function to adjust the value to get your range, so you could use something similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Your_Table
WHERE app_receipt_date > DATEADD(week,-6,GETDATE());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting an error that says ORA-00904: "DATEADD":invalid identifier

Comment: Ah, you're using Oracle.  To get today's date in Oracle, you can use **select sysdate from dual**.  You can then add/subtract from this date just by adding or subtracting from it, e.g. yesterday's date would be **select sysdate-1 from dual** etc.